# Use Edge Webview instead of IE Webview for Windows 8.1 Cordova Metro apps

Tags: windows, cordova, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows-10-universal

Is there any ways, we can use Edge webview instead of IE webview for windows 8.1 apps? As i know, Windows 8.1 app runs on Windows 10 too but i just want to update the webview. Only windows 10 apps supports edge webview.

If i migrate my app from 8.1 to 10 (universal) then lots of things needs to be changed and that will introduce much complexity and consume more time in my app. So, i want to stick with windows 8.1 and just update the webview to edge. Is it possible?

I tried `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` but it still renders on IE webview (navigator command in console)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field, but I can't imagine that this is possible, because you can't ensure that there's edge installed on a Win 8 system. I guess upgrading your app is the solution of choice here...

Comment: Thanks for your view.